# converting ShaderGraph ScreenPosition-Raw & SceneDepth node to Fragment shader code

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, shader-graph

I have a complex fragment shader and i realized that i need to use two nodes from the shader graph nodes function

1 - [image: Screen Position - Raw]
2 - [image: Scene Depth]

I know shader graph generates it's code into *surface Shader* instead of *fragment shader*, which made things hard for me to figure out how get the same exact results but in **Fragment shader**.

the cloest result I've seen was `v.screenSpace.xy / v.screenSpace.w;` where `screenSpace = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);`

I've tried many other things, none of them worked or worth mentioning
Thanks for your help.